NSolve not working with RegionMember in version 14.0
The following code used to work, I think, and now NSolve gives an error. It seems to be related to using Regions. I can't seem to work out any more than that.
$VersionNumber
(* 14. *)

shape1 = Cone[];
shape2 = Cuboid[];
(*add shapes in this list to make a more complicated shape*)
shapes = {shape1, shape2};

(*this constains the shapes so the shape is considered as a whole*)
constraints[shapes__] := 
 And[## & @@ (Not /@ 
      Through[(RegionMember[RegionIntersection@##] & @@@ 
          Subsets[{shapes}, {2}])@#]), 
   RegionMember[RegionUnion @@ (RegionBoundary /@ {shapes})]@#] &

intersections[l_, s__] := 
 NSolve[# ∈ l && constraints[s][#], #] &@({x, y, 
     z}[[;; RegionEmbeddingDimension[l]]])

direction = {-0.2, -0.2, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 1.5};

line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
        
(*find intersection*)
intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes;

points = Point[{x, y, z}] /. intersection;

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], shapes}, line, {Red, points}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True]


NSolve::naqs. (x|y|z)∈R ... is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.


I also get an error in 14.1, but no error in 13.0.

Error in 13.3 too

However, 13.1 works

Perhaps we need not use RegionMember .  What do you want to plot?

Edit

Use Reduce with Rationalize and test the case when the regions is disjoin.

Clear["Global`*"];
shape1 = Cone[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -2}}, 1/2];
shape2 = Cuboid[];
shapes = {shape1, shape2};
direction = {-0.2, -0.2, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 1.5};
reg = RegionUnion@shapes;
line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
sol = Reduce[{RegionMember[Rationalize[reg, 0], 
     Rationalize[point + t*direction, 0]], t >= 0}, t];
tValues = ToRules[CylindricalDecomposition[sol, t, "Boundary"]];
points = Rationalize[point + t*direction, 0] /. {tValues};
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], shapes}, line, {Red, Point[points]}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True]


Original

11.3, 12.2, 12.3 also work for the original code, but 13.3 not.

We use NMinimize and NMaximize to find the boundary intersection points.


Clear["Global`*"];
shape1 = Cone[];
shape2 = Cuboid[];
shapes = {shape1, shape2};
direction = {-0.2, -0.2, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 1.5};
reg = RegionUnion@shapes;
line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
sol1 = NMaximize[{t, 
    point + t*direction ∈ RegionUnion@shapes}, t];
sol2 = NMinimize[{t, 
    point + t*direction ∈ RegionUnion@shapes}, t];
p1 = point + t*direction /. sol1[[2]]
p2 = point + t*direction /. sol2[[2]]
points = {p1, p2};
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], shapes}, line, {Red, Point[points]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True]


{0., 0., -1.}.


{0.4, 0.4, 1.}.


